# Custom path for resourceful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rack, rails-routing

I'd like to be able to do ...

resources :posts

... and be able to customize the contextual url to be ...

`:year/:month/:day/:id`

... and **still** be able to do ...

`post_path post`

This would have it generate `/2012/1/1/something-something`.

However it appears I have to ...

`get ':year/:id' => 'posts#show', as: 'posts'`

Then in the view I have to ...

`post_path post.year, post.id` instead of `post_path post`

Is there anyway to have the post_path helper pick up the extra parameters it needs for the route?

If not this seems like it might be worth a feature request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like:

```
match "posts/:year/:month/:day/:id" => "posts#show", :constraints => { :year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/ }
```